# "message": "Session expired or invalid","errorCode": "INVALID_SESSION_ID" in postman

Tags: rest-api, postman

Goal : configure Salesforce to enable an external system to use SF APIs.
I am fully discovering the full picture and i am missing pieces..

I created a connected app, enabling API.
In postman desktop, I downloaded the SF collections and i created an hopefully 'forever token' using oAuth2 and got a response.
I tested the access token selecting Bearer token and {{_endpoint}}/services/data/v{{version}}/limits/recordCount?sObjects=Account,Contact,Lead

This worked fine
Now i send over the token to the external system guys and in postman ( they don't have the SF collection) but they
tried the same {{_endpoint}}/services/data/v{{version}}/limits/recordCount?sObjects=Account,Contact,Lead

And immediately get         "message": "Session expired or invalid","errorCode": "INVALID_SESSION_ID".

i then retried on my desktop postman all was working so i tried on Web postman in an anonymous window and also get "message": "Session expired or invalid","errorCode": "INVALID_SESSION_ID".

So My question is what am i doing wrong? have i forgotten a setting somewhere? a little tick somewhere?
( i did try to set the 'Follow auth Header ' on in Settings but same error output)

Any input welcome.
Web view

[image]

Desktop view
[image]

Comment: I was typing out an answer about how access tokens do expire, but the I re-read the question and it working for you in postman (Desktop) but not postman (Web) is odd. Are you sure you're setting the `{{_endpoint}}` and `{{version}}` variables correctly? Are you typing the header name correctly? Some screenshots of your two postman setups (with sensitive information blacked out, naturally) would probably be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Derek. So the process I followed so far is correct then since you didn't ask questions about that ( connected app + creation of token via Oauth 2 providing consumer and secret) . If so i will review the variables but i triple checked them already and i keep getting that annoying error, hopefully i'll spot an error.. Now though i do have a question about the access token that expire.. how can I provide some token once for all, i don't understand the refresh token concept..

Comment: I added 2 screen shots, not sure they say much. When you said 'Are you typing the header name correctly?' Where does that go as i didn't type any header name anywhere so this could be my issue.